# DataSet - Ensuring PrimaryKey data when Filling with a query that is an outer join

Tags: c#, database, dataset, dataadapter

When filling a DataSet, I am using the "AddWithKey" value for the DataAdapter's MissingSchemaAction.  According to MSDN:

> Adding schema information to a DataSet
>   before filling it with data ensures
>   that primary key constraints are
>   included with the DataTable objects in
>   the DataSet.

But, when I do the following:

```
DataColumn[] foo = TheDataSet.Tables["Table1"].PrimaryKey;
```

I get foo.Length of 0.  Is there something more that I need to do besides this?:

```
string TheQuery = "SELECT * FROM Table1 LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.EVENT_NUM = Table2.EVENT_USER_NUM;
using (SqlDataAdapter TheDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(TheQuery, TheConnection)
{
    TheDataAdapter.MissingSchemaAction = MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey;
    TheDataAdapter.Fill(TheDataSet, "Table1");
}
```

Note, if my query was:

```
string TheQuery = "SELECT * FROM Table1";
```

All would be fine.  But, I don't get a PrimaryKey if there is a join.  Is this even possible (to get the Primary key)?

EDIT: At first, I didn't realize this was a JOIN.  Although, I've tested INNER JOINS that would return a PrimaryKey.  The culprit seems to be the fact that this is an OUTER JOIN.  Thus, I changed the title.

Comment: Does the table have a primary key?

Comment: New info: Yes, there's a primary key, but I just realized this was on a query that was a JOIN (both tables have a Primary Key)

Comment: please don't include tags like C# in the title. Keep them in the tags, where they belong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/33y2221y%28v=VS.90%29.aspx):

> If the SelectCommand returns the
>   results of an OUTER JOIN, the
>   DataAdapter will not set a PrimaryKey
>   value for the resulting DataTable. You
>   must define the PrimaryKey yourself to
>   ensure that duplicate rows are
>   resolved correctly.